# running time variation Prim

Tags: performance, graph-algorithm

I wanted to find the "minimum spanning tree", given a set A with edges that must be in the "minimum spanning tree" (so it's not a real minimum spanning tree, but given A, it has the least sum of weights). So the "minimum spanning tree" must definitely contain all edges of A. I made some modifications to Prim's algorithm which can be found below. I then wanted to find the running time of this algorithm, however, I'm having trouble with finding the running time to check wheter the intersection of two sets is empty. 
Could somebody please help me? And what would be to total running time then? I already put the running time for each step next to that step, except for "?".

Notation clarification:
δ(W) = {{v ,w} ∈ E : w ∈ W, v ∈ V\W} for W ⊂ V

```
algorithm:


1. T = ∅, W = {v}  for some v ∈ V   O(1)
2.  While W ≠ V                     n iterations
       If (A ∩ δ(W) ≠ ∅) do              ?
           Take e = {v,w}  ∈ (A ∩ δ(W))  O(1)
           T = T ∪ {e}                   O(1)
           W = W ∪ {v,w }                O(1)
       Else
           Find e = {v,w } ∈ δ(W) s.t. ce ≤ cf ∀ f ∈ δ(W)  O(m)  
           T = T ∪ {e}                                     O(1)
           W = W ∪ {v,w }                                  O(1)
   End while
```